# Audio player works in simulator but not on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, audio-player

I have the following code initializing:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
```

Then a button starts the player

```
[_audioPlayer play];
```

So it works fine when I am on the simulator but it doesn't work on my device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to get the path of a file in your app bundle is like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp3"];
```

But if you actually want an `NSURL`, use the following to get it directly:

```
NSURL *soundUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"mp3"];
```

Also, the simulator isn't case sensitive but a real device is. Make sure your file is really named `test.mp3` and not something like `Test.mp3`. Update the name in the code to match the actual filename.

Use the debugger to make sure that `soundURL` isn't `nil`. If not but the audio player still doesn't work, use the `error` parameter to see why:

```
NSError *error = nil;
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:&error];
if (!_audioPlayer) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to create audio player: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: That didn't do anything

Comment: What didn't? I made lots of suggestions. Did you do everything I suggested? Please be specific.

Comment: So sorry, i take that back. Turns out something is wrong with my speakers on my device. I played it through an aux cable and it worked.